# CATextLayer SetFont Xamarin iOS Value cannot be Null

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I encountered this error on iOS simulator version 9.2

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: handle
```

The code below just works on iOS simulator version 8.1

```
Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(16);
....
textLayer = new CATextLayer();
textLayer.ForegroundColor = TextColor.CGColor;
textLayer.SetFont(CGFont.CreateWithFontName(Font.FontDescriptor.Family));
```

Setting the font triggers the mentioned error.

```
textLayer.SetFont(CGFont.CreateWithFontName(Font.FontDescriptor.Family));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- iOS 9 = The system font is `San Fransisco`
- iOS 8 = The system font is `Helvetica Neue`

Use `UIFont.FontDescriptor.Name` instead of `Family`. The full name will always work.

*D.WriteLine(Font.FontDescriptor.Family);

```
`.SF UI Text`
```

*D.WriteLine(Font.FontDescriptor.Name);

```
`.SFUIText-Regular`
```

---

```
var Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(16);
var textLayer = new CATextLayer();
textLayer.ForegroundColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor; // TextColor.CGColor;
textLayer.SetFont(CGFont.CreateWithFontName(Font.FontDescriptor.Name));
```